# Why is .fadeIn('slow') not working here?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a simple gallery with buttons that allow the user to cycle through images. When the user clicks a button and the image changes, I'd like it to fade in but it doesn't appear to be doing anything? Here is what i have:

```
$(function () {
    $("#homeGalleryControls li a").click(function () {
          var image = $(this).attr("rel");
          $('#galleryImage').fadeIn('slow');
          $('#galleryImage').attr("src", image);
          $('.galleryButton').attr("src", "/Content/Images/Design/btn_default.gif");
          $(this).find('img').attr("src", "/Content/Images/Design/btn_checked.gif");
    });
});
```

Can anyone see what's wrong here?

Thankyou

Comment: Check to see if your function is actually being fired at all.  Stick an alert just before your image declaration and see if it pops up on screen when you click the button.

Comment: BTW is there a reason you don't stop the default behavior?

Comment: @JonTaylor It is being fired because the images are switching as intended

Comment: The `.fadeIn()` function will appear to do nothing if the element is already visible, which appears to be the case. You could call `.fadeOut()`, then switch the image `src`, then call `.fadeIn()`.

Comment: Very true, you need to set its opactiy to 0 then use fadeIn.

Comment: I'll give those suggestions a try

Comment: Actually in the jquery example it just sets the display:none on the div, you could try this on the img instead.  Then  call fadein http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I've tried that before. It fades the newly selected image out, then in, which is not what i want.

Comment: Any particular reason you're grabbing the "rel" attribute of the link and setting it as "src" of the #galleryImage ? Also, a HTML sample would be helpful.

Comment: I'm using the `rel` attribute to hold the location of the image that should be displayed in the gallery div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, used the following incase anyone else was wondering:

```
$(function () {
        $("#homeGalleryControls li a").click(function () {
            var image = $(this).attr("rel");
            $('#galleryImage').fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $('#galleryImage').attr("src", image);
                $('#galleryImage').fadeIn('slow');
            });
            $('.galleryButton').attr("src", "/Content/Images/Design/btn_default.gif");
            $(this).find('img').attr("src", "/Content/Images/Design/btn_checked.gif");
        });
    });
```

Comment: You can use `$('#galleryImage').fadeOut(0, function () { ` to set the time to 0 ms.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that **[fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)** and fadeOut do not work on an img element directly so I added a container div.
I've create a **[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/owejet/48/edit)** (because JSFiddle is down) that demonstrates what you want to do.
Here is a **[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/owejet/49/edit)** example without the container div and you can see it is **not** working.

The HTML

```
<div id="imageContainer">
  <img id="image" />
</div>
```

The JavaScript Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var image$ = $("#image"),
      imageContainer$ = $("#imageContainer"),
      parent$ = imageContainer$.parent();

  imageContainer$.fadeOut(0, function () {
    imageContainer$.detach();

    image$.on("load", function () {
      imageContainer$.fadeIn(400);
    });

    image$.attr("src", "http://www.waleoyediran.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/stackoverflow.png");

    parent$.append(imageContainer$);
  });
});
```

I also changed the order around. So first the image is downloaded and only when it is available it will fadeIn.

Comment: `I'm wondering why you fadeIn first and then change the image. Is this really what you want? Or do you want to set the src first and then fadIn?`. I want to set the `src` of the new image, then fade it in. So `user clicks button > new src is set > fade in > new image shown`. Would setting the opacity of the currently selected image to 0 and then calling fade in work? Forgive me but I've not touched much jQuery before..

Comment: Hi Bart, i solved this a little while ago. Thankyou for taking the time to answer though. +1

Comment: @Duane You're welcome! I suggest you fadeIn on the load event of the image. Otherwise the fadeIn can start before the images is downloaded.