# Can't fade in an image loaded with jquery

Tags: jquery, image, fadein

I'm a novice at jQuery and I don't understand why the image displays, but it doesn't fade in as the jQuery documentation suggests.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>slide show test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="image" alt="slide" style="opacity:0.5;"/>
<script>
var x="tiananmen-square-600.webp";
$("#image").attr('src', x, function() {
        $("#image").fadeIn( "slow");
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Help, please.

Comment: Maybe this can shed some light? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11502511/4861760

Comment: [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) doesn't accept a 3rd parameter. I think you want `$('#image').attr('src', x).fadeIn('slow')`

Comment: ```$('#image').attr('src', x).fadeIn('slow')``` didn't work.

Comment: I made it work by making these changes:

```
<img id="image" alt="slide"/>
<script>
var x="tiananmen-square-600.webp";
$("#image").fadeOut( "fast");
$("#image").attr('src', x);
$("#image").fadeIn( "slow");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) doesn't accept a 3rd parameter.

I think you want something like this

```js
const x = "https://picsum.photos/200/300";

const image = $("#image").hide().attr("src", x);

image[0].decode().then(() => {
  image.fadeIn("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image" />
```

That is

1. Select the `#image` element
2. Initially hide it
3. Set it's `src` attribute
4. Wait for the image data to become available (see [decode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode))
5. Fade it in

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by removing the opaque styling in the img tag and replacing the jQuery code with this:

```
$("#image").fadeOut(0);
$("#image").attr('src', x);
$("#image").fadeIn("slow");
```